# What is the Difference between asssigning layer and assigning weight of layer?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, embedding

Imagine i have two code examples:

```
model.embedding = new_emb
```

and

```
model.shared.weight = new_emb.weight
```

What would be the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign a layer weight, the assigned layer weight has to have the same shape as the current layer weight.

If you assign a new layer, you can assign any layer (as long as it can handle the input tensor shape and return the correct output tensor shape).

Comment: Thank you, but in torch.nn.embedding, even when layers have different shape, i can assign their weights to each other. How that can work? For example: if embedding layer x has shape (1000,768) , i can assign x's weight to embedding layer y's weight(y's shape is 2000,768) . How this can work?

Comment: Please give an example on how you assign the weights.